# Multiple choice quiz using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python in a class project and I want to make a multiple choice German quiz and I have pretty much all I want, but I don't know how to make the quiz so people can't just press the correct answer over and over and add to their score.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def main():

    tabs.add(frame1, text="Q1")
    tabs.add(frame2, text="Q2")
    tabs.add(frame3, text="Q3")

    Label(frame1, text="What is the capitol of Germany?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(frame1, text="Berlin",command=correct).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(frame1, text="Poland",command=incorrect).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(frame1, text="Auschwitz",command=incorrect).grid(row=3,column=3)

    Label(frame2, text="What does 'Wo ist die Toilette' mean?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(frame2, text="What is the toilet",command=incorrect2).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(frame2, text="Where is the toilet",command=correct2).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(frame2, text="Woah, that's a toilet",command=incorrect2).grid(row=3,column=3)

    Label(frame3, text="What does 'Wie ist dein Name' mean?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(frame3, text="That is my name",command=incorrect3).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(frame3, text="Why is that your name",command=incorrect3).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(frame3, text="What is your name",command=correct3).grid(row=3,column=3)
    tabs.pack()

    Label(root, text="Total:").pack()
    Label(root, textvariable=total).pack()


def correct():
    Label(frame1,text="Correct! Good job").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()
def incorrect():
    Label(frame1,text="Incorrect, try again").grid(row=1,column=2)
def correct2():
    Label(frame2,text="Correct! Good job").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()
def incorrect2():
    Label(frame2,text="Incorrect, try again").grid(row=1,column=2)
def correct3():
    Label(frame3,text="Correct! Good job").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()
def incorrect3():
    Label(frame3,text="Incorrect, try again").grid(row=1,column=2)
def counter():
    total.set(total.get() + 1)

root = Tk()
root.title("German Quiz!")
total = IntVar()

tabs=ttk.Notebook(root)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
frame3 = ttk.Frame(tabs)

main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, add your code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe make a `questions_correct = [False, False, False]` list, and update the index in each `correct` method?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I would like for you to elaborate because I'm not very experienced in python, I have maybe 2 months under my belt. I'm also new on stack overflow as well.